# Riddle: What is this simple common tool?

Tags: riddle

Each tool is capable of being used many times in many situations, and it is usually kept for days, months, or even years before being thrown away; however, almost always, it is used only once. The modern household typically has several of them. Compared to most familiar tools, it is of relatively modern origin. Formerly, we managed without it by various improvisations; but this tool does the job more conveniently and neatly. Although most adults in the modern world know what it is used for, and how to use it, the tool does not have an established name (like a hammer or screwdriver); so I expect that you would need more than a single word to identify it.

Comment: One thing that comes to mind is those thin plastic [freezer box thingies](https://i.imgur.com/2qtoj96.png) that you use to store loose screws because you didn't have anything sturdier handy. They won't take more than one round of freezing berries, leftovers, or whatever.

Answer (score 2):

There could be many such items, and this could be just me, but what came to mind right away was -

> A [Zip Tie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cable_tie)

Why

> To be honest, I didn't even knew what's it called but I have several lying around me which came with something that I bought. It was used once by the people who used it to fasten the items I bought. And I am pretty sure I will dispose it very soon. It could have been invented in around 1950's but where I live, its not very old and I feel other conventional methods like tying a knot is always easy and mostly used to pack a bag instead of using zip tie. Most modern folks might be using it, but old school like me refrain using it considering its harmful to environment and well, not really easy to unlock it. :)

Comment: Would you really say these can be used 'many times'? A couple at most usually, due to wear and tear (most are specifically designed to be single-use). Plus, I'd say its name is pretty straightforward and well established too (albeit it has many)!

Comment: @Stiv How many times it can be used is very subjective yes :) So is the word "many". About the name, as I mentioned, it could be just me who didn't knew what its called and prolly I will again forget what its called in a few days from now :D

Comment: It seems like zip tie is a pretty widely-accepted name.

Answer (score 2):

It could be

> A floss pick 
>  [image]

Not necessarily a "Household Tool" but used by a household as a type of tool

> replacing long, messy strands of dental floss placed between one's fingers.

Normally used once, more convenient and neat as well.